# How to parse date and time in custom format according to correct time zone

Tags: ruby, timezone

```
> input = "12/31/2015 23:59"
> format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
> Time.zone = "US/Eastern"
> Time.zone.utc_offset
=> -18000

> Time.strptime(input, format)
 => 2015-12-31 23:59:00 +0100

> DateTime.strptime(input, format)
 => Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:59:00 +0000
```

Whereas I want to get `2015-12-31 23:59:00 -0500`

As you can see both versions of strptime ignore configured time zone (one uses UTC and one uses system/machine time zone).

How to parse given input in custom format in `Time.zone`?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to convert parsed time into ISO string, strip incorrect time zone information and parse again, this time using Time.zone.parse which uses Time.zone:

```
> parsed = Time.strptime(input, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
> Time.zone.parse(parsed.to_s.gsub(/\+\d\d:?\d\d/, ""))
=> 2015-12-31 23:59:00 -0500
```

One solution would be to convert parsed time into ISO string, strip incorrect time zone information and parse again, this time using Time.zone.parse which uses Time.zone:

```
> parsed = Time.strptime(input, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
> Time.zone.parse(parsed.to_s.gsub(/\+\d\d:?\d\d/, ""))
=> 2015-12-31 23:59:00 -0500
```

It's also possible to append time zone to input (and format):

```
> DateTime.strptime(input + Time.zone.name, format + " %Z")
=> Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:59:00 -0500
```

Both solutions seem like a hackish and I was hoping something more elegant.